# How to change pattern with AWK command in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I need your help in awk command, I have a below input file:

**sudo su - USER1 -c $Job_dir/abcd.sh abcd pdwd line1**

**sudo su - USER2 -c $Job_dir/ancd.sh abcd pdwd line2**

I want to result like this for all lines (want to add double quotes before $ and at the end of the line :

**sudo su - USER1 -c "$Job_dir/abcd.sh abcd pdwd line1"**

**sudo su - USER2 -c "$Job_dir/ancd.sh abcd pdwd line2"**

Comment: What have you tried, how did it fail? We encourage people to share their attempts rather than using [so] as a free code-writing service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The awk-file "test.awk" will "add double quotes before $ and at the end of the line". 
 (In case, the line does not include $, it will just print the line as it is.)

```
{
   len=length($0);
   pos=-1;
   for(i=0;i<len;i++)
   {
      if(substr($0,i,1)=="$")
      {
         pos=i;
         printf("%s\"%s\"\n",substr($0,1,pos-1),substr($0,pos,len-pos));
      }
   }
   if(pos==-1) print;
}
```

Run it by

```
awk -f test.awk textfile.txt > result.txt
```

The "textfile.txt" is the input file and "result.txt" is the output file.

A shorter version of "test.awk" is with using "index" command to find "$" in the line, see below:

```
{
   s=index($0,"$")
   if(s!=0)
   printf("%s\"%s\"\n",substr($0,1,s-1),substr($0,s,length($0)-s));
   else
   print;
}
```

Comment: Hi Sid Coder, 

Thanks for your help but, I need to put this in below: 

INPUTFILE_2="/d/deepak.txt"
while OutsideFile= read -r line2
do 
 #echo "$line2"
 if [ -f "$line2" ]; then
 INPUTFILE=$line2
 
 #----------------
 #Main Function
 #----------------

while InsideFile= read line
do
 #echo "$line" 
if [ -f "$line" ]; then
s=$line
awk 
'{
   s=index($0,"$")
   if(s!=0)
   printf("%s\"%s\"\n",substr($0,1,s-1),substr($0,s,length($0)-s));
   else
   print;
}' 
fi; 
done < "$INPUTFILE"
fi;

done < "$INPUTFILE_2"